# DevMode causing stuck entry saves

Tags: devmode

Ok so this is part I need help part heads up for others. The back story... I a client messaged me saying that they couldn't save posts anymore for specific entries. I noticed the ones that were having issues were the larger ones. The entries are fairly complex with the supertable plugin. I tried EVERYTHING I could to diagnose the problem, modifying every server setting etc. I realized it worked locally but not remote. I also realized it worked fine on my phone but not my machine. it worked on a co-workers air but not my macbook pro. craziness. I did eventually get it to work but I'm not sure why.

Switching out of DevMode made everything work fine, but that isn't a real acceptable solution for me because I use devMode. I hope anyone struggling with this, sees this but I appeal to some of you more seasoned Craft devs, why the heck is this happening in devMode and only remote on some machines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dev Mode introduces a lot of extra overhead for many processes. It profiles and logs all MySQL queries to the browser's console. For a detailed description of what Dev Mode does, please check out this page of the docs...

> [**What Dev Mode Does**](https://craftcms.com/support/dev-mode)

Specifically, this line is critical...

- *"Dev Mode is definitely **not** suited for production environments."*

Answer (score 3):

I'll be a bit over-the-top here, but this is like complaining that your air conditioning isn't working as well as you'd hope because of the raging fire coming out of the hood of your car.

You should absolutely not be running devMode in any publicly-accessible area — it exposes tons of information about your build, and under some circumstances (like if you use PHP dotenv) will expose server usernames and passwords to users.

Use Craft's multi-environment configuration so that you can set general.php to use devMode on your local, but keep it turned off in production: https://craftcms.com/docs/multi-environment-configs